# Facebook Like box not expanding container div

Tags: css, html, facebook-likebox

I have just copied the code for a Facebook Like box into a new site design I am building but when it loads it's not expanding the containing div.

[image]

Also I've noticed that it will disappear sometimes and the page needs to be refreshed to bring it back.

What is causing it not to expand the div.  I thought it was to do with a float but can't see one that will affect it.

I've attached the xhtml/css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="body_bottom">
            <div class="body_top">
                <div id="header">
                    <img src="images/banner.jpg" />         
                </div>
                <div id="content">

                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div class="sidebar_item">
                        <div class="sidebar_item_top"></div>
                        <div class="sidebar_item_pad">
                            <p>Get updates for our latest news, events and blogs.</p>
                            <form id="addressform" action="/" method="get">
                                <div class="textl1"><label id="namLbl" for="mlName">Name</label><input type="text" id="mlName" name="mlName" /></div>
                                <div class="textl1"><label id="emlLbl" for="mlEmail">Email</label><input type="text" id="mlEmail" name="mlEmail" /></div>
                                <div class="textr1"><input type="submit" id="mlbutton" name="mlbutton" value="" class="button-signup" /></div>
                                <p id="response" style="text-align: left"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar_item_bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sidebar_item">
                        <div class="sidebar_item_top"></div>
                        <div class="sidebar_item_pad">
                            <div id="fbook">
                                <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
                                <br  style="clear:both">
                            </div>
                            <div id="fb-root"></div>
                            <script>
                                (function(d, s, id) {
                                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                                    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                                    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=151487781542911";
                                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

                                $(window).bind("load resize", function(){
                                    var container_width = $('#fbook').width();
                                    $('#fbook').html('<div class="fb-like-box" ' +
                                    'data-href="https://www.facebook.com/adobegocreate"' +
                                    ' data-width="' + container_width + '" data-height="730" data-show-faces="true" ' +
                                    'data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>');
                                    FB.XFBML.parse( );
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar_item_bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="clearboth"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

#header {

}

#container {
    width:1009px;
    margin:20px auto;
}

#largeimage {
    float:left;
    width:943px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 8px;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    width:620px;
    margin: 11px 19px 0 9px;
}

#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:304px;
}

.clearboth {
    clear:both;
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    width: 962px;
    height:208px;border-top:1px dotted #CCCCCC;padding:10px 0;background: #373737 url(../images/sniper_scope.jpg) no-repeat 15px 10px;
    margin: 10px 22px;
}

.body {
    background: url('../images/body_center.png') repeat-y;
    width: 1009px;
}

.body_top {
    background: url('../images/body_top.png') no-repeat;
    width: 1009px;
    padding: 0px 24px;
}

.body_bottom {
    background: url('../images/body_bottom.png') no-repeat bottom;
    width: 1009px;
}

.img_top {
    background: url('../images/img_top.png') no-repeat;
    height: 8px;
    width: 943px;
}

.img_center {
    background: url('../images/img_center.png') repeat-y;
    width: 943px;
}

.img_pad {
    margin: 2px 8px 2px;
}

.img_bottom {
    background: url('../images/img_bottom.png') no-repeat;
    height: 15px;
    width: 943px;
}

#contentimg {
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
}

.content_item_top {
    background: url('../images/content_item_top.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 623px;
}

.content_item {
    width: 623px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.content_item_main {
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    padding: 10px 22px;
}

.content_item_bottom {
    background: url('../images/content_shadow.png') no-repeat;
    height: 9px;
    width: 623px;
}

.sidebar_item_top {
    background: url('../images/sidebar_item_top.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 39px;
    width: 304px;
}

.sidebar_item {
    background: url('../images/sidebar_item_centre.jpg') repeat-y;
    width: 304px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.sidebar_item_pad {
    margin: 5px 26px 12px;
}

.sidebar_item_bottom {
    background: url('../images/sidebar_item_bottom.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 9px;
    width: 304px;
}

ul.footerlist {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:20px 16px;
}

ul.footerlist li {
    font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color: #373737;
}

#footer h5 {
    font-size:120%;
    color: #E5DFCA;
}

#footertop, #footerbottom {width:710px;float:right;}
#footerbottom p{font-size:11px;color:#f0f0f0;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;margin:0;padding:0px;line-height:20px;text-align:left;}
#footertop a{color:#f0f0f0;text-decoration:none;}
#footertop a:hover{color:#c3c3c3;text-decoration:underline;}

h1, h2 {
    margin:0;
    /*font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #1a1e1c;
}

p {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #424242;
    line-height:20px;
}

#fbook {

}
```

Comment: Set a height on the `div`.

Comment: Reloading the like box every time the window is resized is not a good idea.

Comment: I had to set a height on the div like Josh said.  Don't know why as you'd expect it to expand.  Is it because it's an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try an overflow:auto on the container of the facebook embed? So put it on #fbook